# PHP "Notice: Undefined index" is it harmless or a real error?

Tags: php, debugging

While my site was working without any problem I suddenly started to have a really high CPU usage on my server so I started to check the code more carefully and enabled `E_ALL` error reporting.

Then I found out I had a great many of this "notices":

```
Notice: Undefined index: userID in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/header.php on line 8
```

Most or them refer to unset cookies, for example this:

```
$uid = $_COOKIE['userID'];
```

If the user is unlogged I get a notice right there, and every time I use `$uid`.

What I want to know if this: Are this notices harmless or can they really cause any problems in my site? (Speed issues, errors etc.)

Comment: Can you show your `setcookie`?

Comment: In most cases, there not dangerous, but its good practice to deal with them.

Comment: It's not "dangerous" :) but it does matter. Errors slow down PHP.

Comment: My personal preference is to treat *every* `E_NOTICE` as an error and ensure that the application can never generate one, even if it is "harmless."

Comment: @Nikola K. This is my setcookie: `setcookie($name,$value,time() + 2*7*24*60*60,'/','lujanventas.com', false)` Honestly I don't know what the 'false' means but I copy pasted it long ago and it sticked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a notice only, try this code:

```
$uid = isset($_COOKIE['userID']) ? $_COOKIE['userID'] : 0;
```

It is not hamless (depending on the point of view), and you can disable this with error reporting functions, otherwise, the correct way is verify if index exists `isset($_COOKIE['userID'])` and if not, define a default value (`null` for instance)

```
$var = isset($foo) ? $foo : 'default';
```

You need to verify if variable exists, if you don't known it exists or not.

```
$var = 'foo'
if($var == 'foo') { // I known $var is defined, because I have defined it.
    [..]
}

/** 
 * Above, I don't known if user go to mywebsite.com/index.php or
 * mywebsite.com/index.php?foo=bar, so, I need to verify if index is defined
 */
if(isset($_GET['foo']) && $_GET['foo'] == 'bar') {
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Or -1, in case the IDs start from 0 ;)

Comment: @nico I do not think this is common practice

Comment: thanks, I already implemented it. Just a question, how can it hurt my site functioning? (sorry I cannot think of other word)

Comment: @Liso22 Eat bandwidth, slowdown PHP, your user don't want to see errors, you lose credibility (perharps).

Comment: @Gabriel Santos: no, but I have seen it before. And notably the person who did that assigned 0 to admin... I'll let you imagine the disaster that could bring :)

Comment: @Liso Simple: if you're trying to work with values/variables that don't exist, your application by definition enters into an unknown state. You wanted to use the value of `$_COOKIE['userId']` and expected it to be a numeric string. But that value didn't exist. Now what? This may or may not lead to errors down the line. You need to expect and explicitly handle the case of "value may not exist" so you are 100% sure how your application is going to behave in that case.

Comment: I understand, the problem is that this "notice" even appears when you check if a variable exists. EG: `if(!$var)` what can be done in this case? There is absolutely no way to check if a cookie exists without getting the error unless of course if you turn error reporting off

Comment: @Liso22 If you do `if(!$var)` when `$var` does not exists, you will get errors. You need to do: `if(isset($var) && !$var)` which verify if `$var` is defined and `false`.

Comment: A useful shorthand for isset() and both options is a double question mark: `$var = $foo ?? : 'default'`. It became available since PHP 7.0

Answer (score 2):

Those notices will cause a little bit of a speed problem, because raising a notice costs some extra effort.

The main problem though is that this is a serious error. You are trying to work with something that doesn't exist. This may or may not lead to Bad Things Happening, but it means your program is not correct. Since you should always develop with error reporting on full power to see and solve actual problems, notices about undefined indexes or undefined variables are serious and need to be solved. *Anything* that PHP complains about is serious and needs to be solved. See [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/).

Answer (score 1):

Notices are in general harmless, yet they may indicate a poor application design. In general it is always a good idea to utilize available PHP tools (i.e `isset($someVar)`) to make sure that your business logic is taking proper care of variable initialization. When you see no such notices with E_ALL error reporting setting, it's always better.

Answer (score 0):

The Notice warning is in the first point of view harmless, but you should keep in mind, that the programming is not right and it might be causes errors on following lines.

In your example it es better to use

```
$uid = isset($_COOKIE['userID'])?$_COOKIE['userID']:0;
```

So you can be sure, that $uid always has a value and when the value greater then 0 you have a falid userId ...